# Mojo Execution from release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, mojo

I want to write a mojo, which responsibility is to validate the POM against a set of rules (in addition to those specified by Maven). As an example, it'll make sure there's an `organization` element, and that it is populated with the company's details.

This plugin would have the `validate` phase defined as its default phase, and it would go in the company's parent pom, so that it will be executed upon any build.

The issue is that there are different set of rules that should be applied for snapshot and for release builds.

Now, maven release plugin executes a `clean verify` after it had done its manipulations (i.e., after `release:prepare`). And so, my plugin will be executed at this point. Cool.

The thing is, that since it is in the release context, I need to apply the release set of rules. But I cannot tell it is in a release context; I have no idea who/what had triggered it - "regular" build, or as a "sub-process" of `release:prepare`. There's no indication whatsoever...

One solution could be to have the `preparationGoals` populated with, for example, `clean verify  -DisRelease=true`, where `isRelease` is a parameter the plugin queries in order to apply the correct set of rules.

But I do not like this idea; it feels like a hack, and too fragile...

So the question is:

Is there a way to tell what's the context of the execution of the plugin, so that I can tell a snapshot from a release? Is there a way to bind a configuration to a goal, rather than to a phase (as in release it is not a phase, but rather a `release:prepare` goal)? Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Ohad

------------------ EDIT --------------------

Due to some misunderstandings, I am giving a possible example:

Let's say the organization idea of version is of the format: `{number}.{number}.P-{number}`, for whatever reason.

So, in "regular" build there will be a check that the version is in the format `{number}.{number}.P-{number}-SNAPSHOT`, and in case of release, it'll check that it is in the format of `{number}.{number}.P-{number}`.

The POM starts with the version with `-SNAPSHOT`, while in CI, and it passes validations. Then, the developer wants to release it. So a `release:prepare` is executed, chopping of the `-SNAPSHOT`. Then, as the default of `preparationGoals` is `clean install`, the validation rules are executed on the *manipulated* POM (where the version is without the `-SNAPSHOT`). It will fail, as it (wrongly) expects the version to be with `-SNAPSHOT`.

So how can I signal it, that "release" validations should be executed?

Thanks again

Comment: Writing such rules is a job for maven-enforcer-plugin where you can write your own rules if your like?. You can use the option `useReleaseProfile` in maven-release-plugin to let activate the profile `release-profile` during the release:perform...?

Comment: khmarbaise, not sure I get it... Let's say I write custom rules using maven-enforcer-plugin API. I have set of rules to apply for release and other I need to apply for "regular" build. How can I differ one from the other? You say - `useReleaseProfile`. But the default `preparationGoals` of `release:prepare` is `clean verify`. There will be no `useReleaseProfile` in this case, meaning, the code will apply the "regular" build set of rules, not the release... (and it'll fail, as the checks are after POM manipulation). Please elaborate.

Comment: Take a look here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles

Comment: @khmarbaise, thank you for your prompt response. I did look at the specified URL, but I'm afraid I do not see connection. If I understand you right, you suggest to query this flag - if `true` - I am in release flow, otherwise - I am in a "regular" build flow. But this is wrong. This flag is defined for `release:perform`, while the problem is with `release:prepare`. As specified in [https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals], the default `preparationGoals` are `clean verify`. When it runs, i can't tell it is was due to `release:prepare`.

Comment: No via a profile you can use that to recognize if in release or not.

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks again. But I feel your missing something, the profile inherited, `release-profile`, is for `release:perform`. The issue is with `release:prepare`. Plus, again, `release:prepare` runs `clean install` by default, with no profiles. See 5th bullet at <https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html>. and <https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals>. So it's like a "subprocess" of `release:perform`, and not `release:perform` itself